# How to create Singleton connection to DB?

Tags: php, database, oop, connection, singleton

I have started work with OOP, and i have problems with creation database connection class.

I used to work with non-OOP PHP so now it is like to start learning something really hard.

Could U help me with creation of class or advise some articles about creation and  using class?

Comment: Revelant - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4596323/1607098

Comment: i have understood.
Can someone advise simple connection class to DB for a newbie?

Comment: One such class would be [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are considered bad practice. You should use Dependency Injection instead.

You will have a single instance of a database class, the concept of a singleton disappears when you're using Dependency Injection.